# How I can force the openssl "s_client" utility to generate predefined random bytes in it's ClientHello?

Tags: tls, openssl

I'm testing my server application (TLS 1.3) using `s_client` program from the `openssl` library and I need to force the `s_client` generating my "random" values in it's ClientHello.
Could you tell me, how can I do it using command line options - where I should point my random sequence to be generated ?

Comment: There is no command line option to set a specific random value in the ClientHello.

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich, may be it is possible to do it programmatically (rebuild s_client after adding some API calls) ? I use s_client for debugging my server only. So I don't use openssl directly as a library for my programming.

Comment: Since openssl is open source you could adapt it to your needs. But from my understanding there is no API inside openssl which would make what you are trying to do easy to implement. Anyway, how this could be done is a programming question, i.e. off-topic here.

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich, thank you very much!